# Angular js directive which works as internal js is not working as external js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can anyone help me

Same angular code. Works fine as internal js. But not working as external js

Comment: add the code snippets and detailed description. what do you mean by internal js and external js?

Comment: let me guess: your "directive file" is loaded faster than Angular itself. So you are getting error like "angular is undefined" in browser console